# How can I get the timezone of given gps coordinates on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timezone, gps

My question is simple. I have the GPS coordinates of a place and I need to know, in what time zone (and daylight saving settings) is on that place. Is any easy solution for this problem in objective c?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the `MKReverseGeocoder` class added in MapKit with 3.0 will give you such information, unfortunately. That might make for a good Radar enhancement request, eh? (http://bugreporter.apple.com)

However, with a quick Google search, I found http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone - it appears you could query that and get a nice XML result back. Just be sure to obey the usage restrictions listed at the top of that page.

Answer (score 0):

[DRT Engine](http://drtengine.com/pages/geo_get_timezone) can give you a timezone offset based on latitude/longitude coordinates and a datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

Geonames.org has a REST style free web service that provides [geolocation to timezone conversion](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone) under CC attribution license. Response is XML or JSON.

Comment: Please check Geonames' "Terms and Conditions" before you throw your weight behind this solution.  They will allow up to 30,000 hits per day per app with a max of 2,000 per hour.  After the limit is reached, they throw an exception.  If your app can comfortably stay within this limit, you're golden.  If your app becomes wildly popular, you can buy Premium Service on the order of 1M hits for 250 Euro.  Better budget now.